# How to display 100,000 records with pagination in visualforce page

Tags: standardsetcontroller, pagination

I have 100000 records in my database

I am unable get records by soql as I am getting governor limit error.

Guys, give me example code with pagination

Comment: Why would you need to show so many records, if i was user i dont think i would be scanning through 100,000 records.. you should definitely think about using filters in your where clause to restrict the no of records you are querying

Comment: NO my client wanting to be happen

Comment: Hey @Sunny and welcome to SFSE. Contributors are trying to divine your requirements and propose alternatives so hope you can be receptive to that. OFFSET clause has a hard limit of 2000. A very appropriate solution is be to use the QueryLocator and StandardSetController without reinventing the pagination aspect. Be mindful that attempting to resolve the entire data set to a list by using getRecords() will blow up with large collections.

Comment: this reads like "please do my work for me"

Answer (score 5):

Set readOnly=true at the page level to query upto a maximum of 1M (10 lakh) records.

```
<apex:page readOnly="true" controller="xxxxx">
.....
</apex:page>
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm

Answer (score 4):

This may help you out -[Pagination using List controller](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_pagination.htm), you can also look into following post by [Jeff Douglas](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/07/14/visualforce-page-with-pagination/)

Comment: NO my pagination working fine but i am anable to query for 100000 records

Comment: There is a salesforce governor limit were 50,000 is the maximum number of records that can be queried using SOQL per request

Comment: Yes but i need to display 100000 records with pagination If u have any code pls send me,
NOte: with any no of queries

Comment: Can you please post the error your getting.

Comment: I am using
Query: 'select id,name from oppertunity limit 200 offset 0'
List<oppertunities> = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
but it is returning o records

Comment: I think off set is not working
If i remove offet it is workin